# How to remove k-state-focused from Kendo multi-select select box?

Tags: angularjs, kendo-ui

I am using Kendo popup with kendo multi-select select box for multi selection from the list.

The kendo popup also has text box.

```
<input type="text" class="form-control" />
<select class="form-control" kendo-multi-select k-options="selectOptions" 
    data-placeholder="None" k-data-source="credentials" k-data-text-field="'text'" 
    style="width:100%;" k-data-value-field="'id'" k-ng-model="credentialsReq" 
    k-value-primitive="false" multiple="multiple"></select>
```

I want to focus the text box when the popup opens** but the select box is always focusing. When clicking on the popup, k-state-focused class is always adding with multi-select select box.

How can i fix this?

Thanks,
Priya

Comment: Same problem here, have you found a solution ?